# git for windows setup post-receive hook

Tags: git, hook, githooks, tortoisegit

I am desperately trying to set up a post-receive hook on a git bare repo on a windows share. TortoiseGit offers many kinds of hooks but the post-receive hook. You can check the supported kinds here:

[image]

Hope you have an idea how I can set up this. Using the post-receive-hook I would like to build my sources automatically.

I am using Windows 10 an Git for Windows 2.16.2 and TortoiseGit 2.6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between TortoiseGit hooks and vanilla Git hooks.

TortoiseGit has its own hooks which are not honoured by vanilla Git and executed exclusively by TortoiseGit.

For configuring vanilla Git hooks (such as the post-receive-hook), there are no dialogs in TortoiseGit as of 2.6.0. You have to configure those hooks manually (look inside the hooks folder of you bare repository): https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
When I implement a post-receive-hook like explained it works fine, when executing "git push" from command line. but when I use TortoiseGit to push my sources it is not firing. 
Do you have an idea whats the issue here?

Comment: What do you mean by its not fired? Have you tried to print some debug info at the beginning? - All what TortoiseGit does is also just to call git push.

Comment: By "fire" I meant, that the hook is not executed. But today I tried it again and everything work smooth and fine. Thanks for your help